# How do I fetch the metadata of a torrent using an Infohash?

Tags: bittorrent, dht, torrent

I am assuming that after finding peers using that Infohash you send handshake messages until one peer establishes a connection. But I can't seem to find any packet in Wireshark that has the metadata in it. If possible can you show me how a metadata query looks like?

The only thing I've found about metadata was bep 9 but it was kinda hard for me to understand and I didn't find anything in Wireshark similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already found the relevant [BEP 9](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0009.html). To implement it you first have to implement [BEP 10](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0010.html) and then check the extension header whether the peer supports BEP 9 and if it does send a series of extension messages with the appropriate negotiated IDs carrying a metadata request message.

You should be seeing the extension handshake message in most bittorrent connections since many clients support it. You're less likely to see metadata request/data messages (unless you explicitly trigger them in a client) because it's simply a less common operation than downloading the torrent payload.

Comment: Is metadata extension the only way to get it? Also do I send the extension message with the handshake message (i.e an m dictionary combined with the handshake)? One last question do I need to change something in the reserved bits section?

Comment: yes. it's generally sent after the handshake. yes.

Comment: What do the reserved bits represent?

Comment: Btw what's the difference between a torrent payload than metadata

Comment: The torrent payload... well... that's the files you're downloading. Regarding the reserved bitfield: I don't think comments are the right format for this, they're unrelated to the top-level question. You can check various BEPs referring to it.

Comment: Yeah thanks I understood what payload means later. Initially what I meant is when using qbittorrent you can only input the Infohash and get the metadata, aka see which files you're downloading, which seems to be bep 9